# how to split a String with number of character and the character is white space

Tags: java

I want to split a String into lines with a maximum number of characters per line, while splitting only on whitespace.

example :

if my String is `good morning , today is monday good morning , today is monday`
number of characters : 11

the output should be

```
good
morning , 
today is 
monday good
morning , 
today is 
monday
```

this is my code for two rows

```
public String skipRowLettreNumbre(String lettre) {
        String ret = lettre + "\n";
        if (lettre.length() > 36) {
        String after50 = lettre.substring(36);
        for (int i = 0; i < after50.length(); i++) {
            if (after50.substring(i, i + 1).equals(" ")) {
                String part1 = lettre.substring(0, i + 36);
                String part2 = lettre.substring(i + 36, lettre.length());
                ret = part1 + "\n   " + part2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret + "";
}
```

Comment: First show me your code

Comment: I do not understand your question ? white or with ?

Comment: i have in paper en espace of 11 caracters for example if i have 5 caracters i shoud to return a new line wihout splite a world for example if my last world is school i cant write sch \n ool ?

Comment: What if a word is longer than 11 characters?

Comment: i havn't a word longer than 11 , 11 just an example

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public String breakLines(String input, int maxWidth) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int charCount = 0;
    for(String word : input.split("\\s")) {
        if(charCount > 0) {
            if(charCount + word.length() + 1 > maxWidth) {
                charCount = 0;
                sb.append('\n');
            } else {
                charCount++;
                sb.append(' ');
            }
        }
        charCount += word.length();
        sb.append(word);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note: This method will replace all whitespace characters with single spaces (or line breaks).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but wouldn't a `str.trim().split(" ")` do the job?

```
String str = "good morning , today is monday good morning , today is monday ";

String[] arrayStr = str.trim().split(" ");
```

If you want the number of occurences just take `int a = arrayStr.length -1`

**EDIT:**
Still can't get exactly what you want. As I understood you want to split the string with fixed characters numbers AND not split words (such as scho\n ol). If so you can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8524979/3735079). Is not an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some googling i found out solution using rexeg matcher:

```
String text = "good morning , today is monday good morning , today is monday ";
String patternString = "(.{1,11}\\s+)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

int count = 0;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
    String match = matcher.group().trim();
    System.out.println(match);
    list.add(match);
}
String[] result = list.toArray(new String[count]);
```

This basically search text for *1 to 11 any characters* (`.{1,11}`) followed by *at least one whitespace* (`\\s+`) and breaks the text into these parts.

Please beware that the input string **must** end with a whitespace in order for this to work, so add an extra space to the end of your string when you use this, or change `\\s+` to `(\\s+|$)` (*at least one whitespace, or the end of string*).

Also, here are tutorials i have followed to write this:

[Java rexeg](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html), [Java regex quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) and [Matcher tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html)

Output:

```
good
morning ,
today is
monday good
morning ,
today is
monday
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems quite unclear, but with what i make of it, you want to split your String based on white space character. Its simple:-

```
String string="good morning , today is monday good morning , today is monday";
String[] arr=string.split(" ");
```

Here arr is your String array that hold all your Strings.

Comment: but i want to limit number of caracters in any String in array

Comment: What do you mean by limit number of characters in any String? do you want to shorten the String, for example reduce the String to include only 9 characters `good morning , today is monday good morning , today`?

Comment: cuting string in parts any  parts has 9 caracters  and dont cat world

Comment: OP is asking for line wrapping, and i think that putting each word on separate line isn't wery much good line wrapping.

Comment: Ohk , sorry I could not make that out from the problem statement, I think then in that case your solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [kajacx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24405971/1553851):

```
public String breakLines(String input, int maxWidth) {
    return input.replaceAll("(\\G.{1," + maxWidth + "})(\\s+|$)", "$1\n"));
}
```